# Sprite won't move or bounce off of walls

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

These sprites get created in a loop, but the issue is that I can't get them to move and bounce off a wall (kinda like the ball in a pong game). I tried the following code and all it does is fall to the bottom and bounce. However, if I disable gravity the ball just won't move. Thanks for the help

```
    let boxTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "movingEnemy.png")

    let box = SKSpriteNode(texture: boxTexture2);
    box.position = randomPos()
    box.name = "enemy";
    box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width / 2)
    box.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
    box.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 4
    box.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 4
    box.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    box.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10 , dy: 10))

    addChild(box);
```

Comment: It could be because you are applying the impulse before the box has been added to the scene. Once you have added the box to the scene try the applyImpulse then. If not successful, increase the impulse values to larger amounts to make sure they are not too weak.

Comment: That fixed it somewhat, but it seems to slowdown overtime

Comment: That's what an impulse acts like. Look into changing the velocity value instead of applying an impulse then. `physicsBody.velocity`

Comment: @JohnM "slow down" because you need to clear frictions parameters and alike...